# Flatten recursive structure, stored as json in Postgres sql, to flat list

Tags: json, postgresql

How to flatten an json-structure in the following way when the original formatting is stored as a json-blob in postgresql and the result should be used from another query in the same database. I'm looking for a solution in SQL (more or less expanded with JSON-capabilities)

Original:

```
{
  "@type": "a",
  "children :[{
    "@type": "b",
    "children": [{
      "@type": "c"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Expected result

```
[{
   "@type": "a"
 },
 {
   "@type": "b"
 },
 {
   "@type": "c"
 }]
```

The examples are simplified, each object in the original have several attributes that should be in the result. Original is a tree with one parent for zero or more children. No circular paths. Depth of the tree is not known but there are likely not more than 10 levels.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgresql 11.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known if you want to do this in PostgreSQL itself, or if you want to use another programming language.
Anyway, this is an implementation in Typescript, but the same concept is applicable to almost any language.

```
type Input = { "@type": string, children?: Input[] }

let result: { "@type": string }[] = []

function flatten(input: Input[]) {
    for (const element of input) {
        result.push({ "@type": element["@type"] });
        if (element.children && element.children.length > 0) {
            flatten(element.children);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunally I need the solution inside postgres using a more or less expanded sql.